# Replace the previous selected image with original image if one clicks on a new image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am using grid view with ImageAdapter to display images. 
I have two set of images that is **mThumbIds** containing original images and **cThumbIds** containing the selected images.

Right now when i click on an image i change the normal image with the selected image. The code is as below:

```
final ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
            iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //iv.setColorFilter(Color.LTGRAY);
                    iv.setImageResource(cThumbIds[position]);
                    //iv.bringToFront();

                    index= position;

                }

            });

            iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
```

But the problem arises when i click on the another image the other image also shows as selected. The correct way would be to show the new image as selected and remove the older one as selected .In other words the older one should revert back to original one.

Please help me on this

Thanks,

Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using a modified copy of the `ImageAdapter` class in [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) and that the code you have posted is in the `getView(int,View,ViewGroup)` method of that class.

You save the index of the image that is selected but you don't save the view itself. You need to save both in order to revert the old image, something like this:

```
private int selectedPosition = -1;
private ImageView selectedView = null;
...
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // I don't understand what this line is about??
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
    // Why not something like this??
    // ImageView iv = new ImageView(mContext);

    iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Set the selected image for the ImageView just pressed.
            iv.setImageResource(cThumbIds[position]);

            // Revert to the original image for the ImageView previously
            // pressed.
            if (selectedPosition != -1) {
                selectedView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[selectedPosition]);
            }

            // Save the position and ImageView just pressed so it can be
            // reverted next time an ImageView is pressed
            selectedPosition = position;
            selectedView = (ImageView) view;
        }
    });

    iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return (iv);
}
```

I'm a bit confused about the line `ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);` though (as I mention in my code example).

Comment: Hi gary thanks for replying using above code is generating two errors: 1) The method setImageResource(Integer) is undefined for the type View (at selectedView.setImageResource) 2) view cannot be resolved to a variable (at selectedView = view)

Comment: The first error is due to the fact that `selectedView` was just a `View` and not an `ImageView`, I have corrected this in the code (look at my edit history to see exactly what needed to be changed). The second error shouldn't be happening if you copied this code exactly. `view` is the parameter in the `onClick` method.

Comment: i have made the changes according to your suggestion it started working

Comment: You should also reuse the second parameter, `convertView` check if this parameter is null. If it is non-null, you can re-use the view. This is fantastic for memory use and performance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a variable and keep the clicked image's id in that. When the user clicks some other image, first reset the other image as per the id in the variable and then replace the variable value with the id of the currently clicked image.